# how to split Map.put to 2 (first put a key, second put a value)?

Tags: java

i have this code

```
Map <String, String> contactsList = new HashMap<>();
 public String putInContactsNameNumber(String name, String number){
    contactsList.put(name, number);
    return number + name;
}
```

(Sit inside of a class name Contacts.)
and after in the Main class got:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)
Contacts contacts = new Contacts();
contacts.contactsList.put("name1","1234");
contacts.contactsList.put("nmae2","2345");
```

wanna ask the user to insert a new key and value,
so added this:

```
String lastName;
String lastNumber;
System.out.println("Enter a name and a phone number");
contacts.putInContactsNameNumber(lastName = scanner.next() ,lastNumber = scanner.next());
System.out.println("Contact is been added.");
System.out.println("name: " + lastName + "\nNumber: " + lastNumber);
```

i wanna split this line:

```
contacts.putInContactsNameNumber(lastName = scanner.next() ,lastNumber = scanner.next());
```

wanna ask the user : "New name: "
then take the first scanner.
and after ask the user: "New phone: "
then take the second scanner.

how i will able to do that ?

thank you for the help :)

Comment: This is the sort of thing you need: `contacts.add(new Contact("name1","1234"));`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply split your statement into multiple smaller statements. You don't have to do it in one single line.

```
System.out.println("Enter a name:");
String lastName = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("Enter a phone number:");
String lastNumber = scanner.nextLine();

contacts.putInContactsNameNumber(lastName, lastNumber);
System.out.println("Contact has been added.");
System.out.println("name: " + lastName + "\nNumber: " + lastNumber);
```

As an added bonus, splitting it up like this improves readability a lot.